# Order by measure, but keep related rows together

Tags: sql-server

I am stuck for some days on my query for ordering my data with a simple query.

As my data are a bit complex, I took an example of the data.

Here is an extract of a table of data (raw data):

```
Products --- Qty --- Info
Chair --- 1 --- Sold
Lamp --- 1 --- Sold
Chair --- 3 --- Sold
Chair --- 1 --- Sold
Chair --- 2 --- Sold
Table --- 4 --- Sold
Computer --- 2 --- Sold
Chair --- 1 --- Returned
Table --- 1 --- Sold
Desk --- 3 --- Sold
Chair --- 2 --- Returned
Etc. (a lot of lines)
```

Here is the result when I do the sum (only the quantity `QTY`, depending if it's SOLD or if it's Returned in two different columns) - ORDER BY : `QtySold`, then `QtyRet`, then `Prod`

```
Prod --- QtySold --- QtyRet --- Info
Chairs --- 95 ------ / ------ Sold
Tables  --- 33 ------ / ------ Sold
Book --- 22 ------ / ------ Sold
Computer --- 22 ------ / ------ Sold
Lamp --- 19 ------ / ------ Sold
Desk --- 11 ------ / ------ Sold
Chairs --- / ------ 5 ------ Returned
Computer --- / ------ 2 ------ Returned
Tables --- / ------ 2 ------ Returned
```

I want to order them differently : in this example, I want to order by `QtySold`, however if `Prod` appears twice, I want the second one to come directly under the first (like chairs - 95 - / - Sold, then Chairs - / - 5 - Returned, etc)

Here is the code (it may contains error as I wrote it directly here):

```
SELECT
Prod=ttt.Prod,
QtySold=ttt.QtySold=CONVERT(Decimal(5,1),SUM(ISNULL(ttt.QtySold,0))),
QtyRet=CONVERT(Decimal(5,1),SUM(ISNULL(ttt.QtyRet,0))),
Info=ttt.Info

FROM(

SELECT    
Prod=nte.Products,
QtySold=(CASE WHEN (ISNULL(nte.Info,'0')='Sold') THEN ISNULL(nte.Qty,0) ELSE 0 END),
QtyRet=(CASE WHEN (ISNULL(nte.Info,'0')='Sold') THEN 0 ELSE ISNULL(nte.Qty,0) END),
Info=nte.Info

FROM
nametableexemple nte

)ttt
GROUP BY ttt.Prod, ttt.Info
ORDER BY ttt.QtySold DESC, ttt.QtyRet DESC, ttt.Prod -- Here is the issue
```

The result I would like to obtain is:

```
Prod --- QtySold --- QtyRet --- Info
Chairs --- 95 ------ / ------ Sold
Chairs --- / ------ 5 ------ Returned --(because Chair is first with 95 Sold)
Tables  --- 33 ------ / ------ Sold
Tables --- / ------ 2 ------ Returned --(because Table is 2nd with 33 Sold)
Book --- 22 ------ / ------ Sold
Computer --- 22 ------ / ------ Sold
Computer --- / ------ 2 ------ Returned --(because Computer is 4th w 22Sold)
Lamp --- 19 ------ / ------ Sold
Desk --- 11 ------ / ------ Sold
```

(Ordering the `QtySold` by DESC : 95 - 33 - 22 - 22 - 19 - 11)
(But the first item (Chairs) as also a "Returned" Info, so I need to make it appear directly under it)

Is that possible to do an "order by" differently? I would like to avoid making an UNION ALL, as my tables contain too many columns.

Comment: Remove the `Info` field from the final results. Rename `QtySold` to `Sold` and `QtyRet` to `Returned`. That way you don't need the `Info` column. Then sort on `QtySold` (Sold) Descending. Don't forget to remove the `ttt.Info` from the `Group By` and `Order By`

Comment: Is it ok if you get the result as - Chair --- 5 (Sold) --- 2 (returned)  in the same row?

Comment: Hello, well it's "OK" to have all in the same columns, but it makes my original table really complexe to read, so that's why i need to avoid that (that's why I'm asking). And for @WEI_DBA I agree that the column INFO is not necessary!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a CTE and enclose your query (without the ORDER BY clause) in it and then do conditional sorting:

```
with cte as (
  <your query here>
)
select * from cte c
order by 
  case 
    when coalesce(c.QtySold, 0) <> 0 then c.QtySold
    else (select QtySold from cte where prod = c.prod and coalesce(QtySold, 0) <> 0) 
  end desc,
  QtySold DESC, prod
```

The function `coalesce()` is needed only if `QtySold` is `null` in the `'Returned'` product rows. 
If it is `0` use this:

```
order by 
  case 
    when c.QtySold <> 0 then c.QtySold
    else (select QtySold from cte where prod = c.prod and QtySold <> 0) 
  end desc,
  QtySold DESC, prod
```

Comment: I will try that tomorrow on my code and I will tell you if it works!

Comment: I have tried this request (the first one), it works perfectly! Thank you for all :)

Answer (score 1):

Try with CTE as below-

```
WITH CTE
AS
(
    SELECT Products,SUM(qty) Q,Info
    FROM your_table
    GROUP BY Products,Info
)

SELECT A.*
FROM CTE2 A
ORDER BY 
(SELECT Q FROM CTE2 B WHERE B.Info = 'Sold' AND B.Products = A.Products)  DESC,
1, 
CASE WHEN info = 'Sold' THEN 1 ELSE 2 END
```

Comment: Hello @mkRabbani, thanks for the answer, that is what I actually use but I need to make them in separate rows (sadly :( )

Comment: More simplified without selecting last column.

Comment: For Same Highest number of Sell for two different product, One more Order need to add in the query. Updated.